# How to get a daily digest of Gmail messages matching a given filter?

Tags: gmail

How can I get an email containing a daily digest consisting of just Subject, sender, date and link to message of Gmail messages matching a given filter?

IFTTT's Email Digest need not apply. It won't send links and is unreliable.

Comment: "migrated from superuser.com". Well that's silly, because I already asked this question here. And now the person who moved it has created a duplicate.

Comment: _"And now the person who moved it has created a duplicate."_ That's the risk when asking off-topic questions. You should just delete one of the duplicates here. Problem solved.